# how to check valid file in windows using perl?

Tags: perl, path

I tried `-e` and `-f` switch, but they don't work.

---

```
print "Enter Board File:";
$brdFile = <>;
$a = -e $brdFile;
printf("Value of A is %d\n",$a);
```

---

Output:

> Enter Board File:C:\SATAHDD.brd Value of A is 0

Location shown above is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the input to remove the newline character:

```
print "Enter Board File:";
$brdFile = <>;
chomp $brdFile;
$a = -e $brdFile;
printf("Value of A is %d\n",$a);
```

If you `use warnings;`, you should get a warning message about the newline.

Comment: Might I suggest addin: not using $a because it is an identifier already used in Perl.  (as well as being a bad variable name generally)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a few improvements to your original code, although I agree with toolic that your problem is almost certainly the missing call to chomp. I present this version of the code that I think represents best practices for this problem.

```
use strict; # Prevents use of undeclared variables, barewords, etc.
use warnings; # Lets you know about runtime problems such as the chomp

print "Enter Board File: ";
my ($brdFile) = <>;
chomp $brdfile;

# Unless you need it later in your program for some reason there is
# no requirement that you store the result in a variable. You can also 
# glue together an output line without using printf if all you need
# is concatenation of string literals and variables
print "\nResult of -e $brdFile is ", -e $brdFile, "\n";
```